# How to execute a bash file from php on a button click

Tags: php, bash, shell

Hi i m  trying to execute a bash file which contains a command to run a script file. I had been trying all possible methods but nothing seem to work. I want to run the file and display the result on the web page.

the bash file contains arguments to execute the script. i tried with

```
system(./bashfile path);
shell_exec(./file path);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $output = shell_exec('./Users/file.sh ');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

but nothing happens. what other ways i could execute the .sh file, help appriciated

Comment: Use absolute path, not relative (i.e. starting with `./`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system(),exec(),shell_exec(),... functions might be disabled because of security.
Also on the phpinfo page of shell_exec you can find:

*This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.*

try:

```
$command = './Users/file.sh';
$output = '';
exec ( $command, $output, $return_var );
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
```